# Firestore to revert all changes if lost connection when in process

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do I do it in *Angular* where if data is being sent to Firestore and in between I lost connection.. So the **half data** which has been successfully written to Firestore should be **removed** .. Or in other case if I am to delete 4 documents consecutively and I lost connection when only 2 document has been deleted... then I want that 2 document to be undeleted....

```
async example() {
  var db = firebase.default.firestore();

  await db.collection('collection1')
    .add(data)
    .then(async (docRef) => {
      // I lost connection here.. So no ID will be updated in xyz..
      // Since this process is incomplete.. I want the data in collection1 to be deleted
      await db.collection('collection2').doc('xyz').update({ id: docRef.id });
    });
}
```

Comment: See This : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.OnDisconnect

Answer (score 2):

Posting this as a community wiki as this is based on the comment provided by [Kevin M. Mansour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14945696).

You can use the [`OnDisconnect()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.OnDisconnect) handler for that, more specific to your case, the `cancel()` handler. As mentioned in the documentation:

> If a write has been queued for this location via a `set()` or `update()` at a parent location, the write at this location will be canceled, though writes to sibling locations will still occur.

So all you have to do in your code is:

```
async example() {
  var db = firebase.default.firestore();
  var ref1 = db.collection('collection1');
  var ref2 = db.collection('collection2');
  ref1.onDisconnect().cancel();
  ref2.onDisconnect().cancel();
  await ref1.add(data)
            .then(async (docRef) => {
                await ref2.doc('xyz').update({ id: docRef.id });
            });
}
```